# Only cold water on my Bravo washing machine

Tags: washing-machine

We have a top loading Bravo washing machine. When we start a load the water comes out very cold no matter what setting the machine is on. I have tried running a load on hot and still only get cold water. What would cause this?

Comment: Questions: First of all do you have hot water elsewhere in the home?  Next, is there a hot water outlet at the washer?  Is it connected?  When you select hot, does the hot water solenoid get activated?  If it gets activated does it open?  If it opens does water flow?  Get the answers to these and I believe you'll find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

More than a few times I have found water lines plugged at the entrance to the valve on the washing machine or at the connection to the supply valve.

Most washers come with screen filters to prevent chunks of material from getting stuck in the valve and flooding the home.

I would turn the hot off, take the hose off at the faucet first if there is a screen is it plugged with rust, scale , pieces of the anode from the hot water tank? 
If no screen there check at the connection to the machine. After cleaning or replacing the screen I will usually get a bucket and high flow the water in the bucket to clear other debris out of the line. Normally washers are close to the water heater you may even feel the water get warm/hot with a gallon or 2 flush. Put the hose back on , check for leaks and see if that fixed the problem. I find it is the problem most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your hot water tank could be off.

Your hot water tank could be far away from your washing machine and the water already in the line from the tank to the washer could be cold.

Maybe you have the shutoff for the hot water going into the machine closed and it is only getting cold water.

Maybe you hooked up the hot and cold water supplies to the opposite on the machine and when you ask for hot it is giving cold.

Take the hot water supply hose off the machine and run it to a bucket.  If no hot water ever comes out problem found.

Comment: I don’t see a reason for the down vote so I reversed it.